# Automate changes to Maven Archetype generated artifact when Archetype changes?

Tags: java, git, maven, continuous-integration, maven-archetype

Maven Archetypes are cool for generating artifacts, but I'm curious whether there are any tools in place to automate keeping generated artifacts in sync as the archetype changes.  To give some additional context on the scenario, imagine...

1. I create my own Maven archetype for a web service based on a proprietary service framework.
2. I generate a couple of different services from the archetype.
3. I add a new feature in the archetype that could theoretically be cleanly merged into all of the generated services.
4. ?
5. The services all magically get the new feature.
6. Profit.

Essentially I'm trying to create a sort of CI workflow around an Archetype to keep artifacts in sync, instead of using it as one time fire and forget artifact creation.

If I had to build this myself, I would probably do something like...

1. Someone pushes changes to the archetype.
2. Generate a vanilla "hello world" service from the archetype.
3. Get a diff of generated services vs the prior "hello world", and an updated diff against the new "hello world".
4. See what changed, use some heuristics to decide whether the changes can be automatically applied.
5. If the changes can be automated, make the changes and send the service owner a CR.  If they can't send an email or create a Jira item for someone to go make the changes.

Before diving in and building, I figured that it was worth looking into whether anyone else has tried something like this in hopes that I can leverage some existing tools.  Thanks in advance for the help!